# Java - Using a while loop to solve a calculation

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm stuck on this question from a mock exam paper. I need to multiply a 'from' number to a 'n' number. In other words: from*(from+1)*(from+2)*...*n.

I need to solve this problem by using a while loop. I have done this so far and not sure what to do.

```
class Fact {

    private int factPartND(final int from, final int n) {

        int c = 1;
        int z = from;
        int y = n;
        int num = 0;

        while (y >= z) {

            num += from * (from + c);// need to stop multiplying from for each
                                     // iteration?
            c++;
            y--;
        }

        return num;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fact f = new Fact();
        int test = f.factPartND(5, 11);
        System.out.println(test);
    }

}
```

Comment: so your output should ideally be 5*6*7*...*11?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your computation is:

```
from * (from + 1) * (from + 2) * ... * (from + n)
```

Think of each *factor* as one iteration of your loop.

So your second iteration should be multiplying your accumulated value by `(from + 1)`, later another iteration by `(from + i)`, where `from < i < n`, and so on until you multiply your accumulated value by `(from + n)`.

Your code is very close - you have `(from + c)` in every iteration, but your arithmetic is wrong.

And as has been mentioned, it's a bit confusing to use `c` *and* `y` to keep track of your loop, when it's sufficient to just test `c`.

Answer (score 4):

There is a problem with your `while` loop **condition**.

```
while(y>=z)
{
    ....
}
```

will execute your code for n+1 times. 
i.e If you want to execute from 5 to 11, this condition will allow to execute till 12.

Better use `while(y>z)` condition in while loop.

Answer (score -2):

```
public class Fact {

    private int factPartND(final int from, final int n) {
        int m = 1;
        int result = from;

        while (m <= n) {
            result *= (from + m++);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fact f = new Fact();
        int test = f.factPartND(5, 8);
        System.out.println(test);
    }
}
```

If you do it with 5, 11 you have an overflow. then you should use BigInteger instead of int.

Comment: this isn't homework, a mod previously asked me to add the 'homework' tag even though it is revision from a past paper

Answer (score -3):

Maybe something like this:

```
package homework;
public class Homework {

    public static int fact(int from, int to){
    int result = 1;
    while(to>0){
        result*=from+to;
        to--;
    }
    return result*from;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(fact(2,4));
    }
}
```

Comment: this isn't homework, a mod previously asked me to add the 'homework' tag even though it is revision from a past paper